# HTML mail headers

Tags: php, html, email, ubuntu, header

I have PHP and Postfix set up at my Ubuntu server. I need to send HTML email from PHP script. The email is sent just fine, but it is displayed as plain text with HTML tags included. Additionally, some headers are also displayed in the email itself.

My guess is, that it has something to do with the headers. I've spent nearly a day searching for a possible solution and haven't found one.

Here's the PHP code:

```
$headers='';
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \r\n";
$headers.="From: ".FROM_EMAIL."\r\n";
mail($email, $vars['title'], $content, $headers);
```

EDIT:

```
 $headers='';
 $headers.='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
 $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
 $headers.='From: Kinesioteip.ee<'.FROM_EMAIL.'>'."\r\n";
 $headers.='To: '.$email."\r\n";
 mail($email, $vars['title'], $content, $headers);
```

Still no luck...

Comment: Dagon, it's valid enough to work in browser.

Comment: srini, $vars['title'] is a variable passed to the function that sends the email. I don't think this is important at the moment.

Comment: i just used headers edit by you and they working fine for me, why don't you show us full mail.php code, may be some other issue causing problem.

Comment: I recently run in the same problem. Similar code was working fine and then suddenly stopped. On Ubuntu 11.10 PHP5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 it fails, however on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 it works perfectly. I guess that something got broken in how Ubuntu 11.10 handles mail in PHP.

Comment: m-t, could you please give me the source of that email. I know that the server adds some default headers, maybe it has something to do with this.

Answer (score 6):

```
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To:' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Admin<youremail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Take a look at the first post again, please. I changed the headers, but had no luck.

Answer (score 5):

can you try changing these lines

```
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \r\n";
```

to

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and see if they work

Answer (score -1):

i think your fourth header is wrong  because FROM_EMAIL variable not having '$'

try

```
        $headers.="From: ".$FROM_EMAIL."\r\n";
```

$vars['title'] change in  to $var

```
 mail($email, $vars, $content, $headers);
```

Comment: Dude, FROM_EMAIL is a constant, it doesn't need dollar sign. I know what variables I pass to the function and they are correct.